# Strange Eclipse Bug When Scrolling Over or Navigating Through Text

Tags: android, eclipse

http://youtu.be/Td4Ziujb_kI

Can't think of any reason why it's doing this. That app is just a TextBox and Button in a relative layout, very very basic.

Answer (score 0):

Could not you do small effort to paste your xml instead of this crap ??

any two, possible reasons are :

1) you defined textView as `fill_parent` width and height so no space for EditText .

2)Editext width/height is zero .

Comment: Uploaded a newer video sorry, it's not an XML problem, it seems to be an Eclipse problem.